# Loop to display time in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and want to render the below code

```
<div className="timeSection">
    <input type="radio" id="control_001" name="select"  />
    <label htmlFor="control_001"><h4>00:00 - 01:00</h4></label>
</div>
<div className="timeSection">
    <input type="radio" id="control_001" name="select"  />
    <label htmlFor="control_001"><h4>01:00 - 02:00</h4></label>
</div>
<div className="timeSection">
    <input type="radio" id="control_001" name="select"  />
    <label htmlFor="control_001"><h4>02:00-03:00</h4></label>
</div>
<div className="timeSection">
    <input type="radio" id="control_001" name="select"  />
    <label htmlFor="control_001"><h4>03:00 - 04:00</h4></label>
</div>
```

I want to run a loop to change the values between `<h4>00:00 - 01:00</h4>` to display between 00 to 24, please assist

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected result? Please show the react component!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

  // I think you can find smarter ways to create this array depends on your logic
  // But you better not do so much array operation inside component, unless you really need it. Because it runs in every render!
  // Do array operations (loops, map, filters) outside of component so that it won't need to run in every render.
  const arr = ["00:00 - 01:00", "01:00 - 02:00"];

  return (
    <div>
      {arr.map((intervalStr)=><div className="timeSection">
        <input type="radio" id="control_001" name="select"  />
        <label htmlFor="control_001"><h4>{intervalStr}</h4></label>
      </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill an array with the numbers, then you can generate the div to each member of the array.

I added a small function to add leading zeros if neccessary.

Something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const times = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
    times.push(i);
  }

  const zeroPad = num => String(num).padStart(2, "0");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {times.map(time => (
        <div className="timeSection">
          <input type="radio" id="control_001" name="select" />
          <label htmlFor="control_001">
            <h4>{`${zeroPad(time)}:00 - ${zeroPad(time + 1)}:00`}</h4>
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-cherry-u3k6h?file=/src/App.js:0-550